# RewriteRule accepts only HTTPS but not HTTP

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have this URL: `https://example.com/folder/cr/other/1234/orders.php`

and have this in my .htaccess file (inside `https://example.com/folder/`):

```
# Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite for cronjobs
RewriteRule ^cr/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/orders\.php$ index.php?module=$1&action=x&id=$2&s=ord [L]
```

This HTTPS url works but when I try with HTTP it doesn't work but redirects to a 404 not found page.

So what I am missing in the rewrite rule?

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` file at the root of `example.com/`? Could you please show its content.

Comment: No, there's no `.htaccess` file directly under `example.com/` the only one exists inside `https://example.com/folder/` folder.

Comment: Make sure both `SSL` and non `SSL` sites are pointing to the same `DocumentRoot`

Comment: @anubhana How can I check that they are pointing to the same `DocumentRoot`?